# use a @types on a custom declared variable

Tags: typescript, cesiumjs

I am using CesiumJs in Angular and installed @types/cesium in my app.

CesiumJs is not handling correctly import like this at the moment and they do not recommend to import it in this way, and I also don't want to import Cesium in every of my file just to get the correct typing of all the methods =>

```
import * as Cesium from 'cesium';
```

Instead, we have to declare a type like following =>

```
declare var Cesium;
```

So that the app assume the package is here, and compile.

The problem is, I have downloaded @types/cesium and I would like to apply the type of Cesium to my declared variable, So that the app know that the Cesium is there but also the type of it.

The type is assigned like this when I import Cesium (using the import) :

(alias) namespace Cesium import Cesium

so I would like to assign the namespace as my type

`declare var Cesium: typeof Cesium;`

but I get

> 'Cesium' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type
>   annotation.

So I tried to fix with

```
type CesiumType = typeof Cesium;

declare var Cesium: CesiumType;
```

But now I get

> Type alias 'CesiumType' circularly references itself.

The problem is the name MUST be Cesium or it will not work.

How do I apply a type to my variable correctly ?